# Gulp+PUG: get all filenames in directory, tranform and inject them in another file

Tags: gulp, pug

I have a PUG filestructure that looks something like this:

```
.
├── _modules
|   ├── _footer
|   |   └── footer.pug
|   └── _header
|   |   └── header.pug
|   └── includes.pug
├── _layouts
|   ├── default.pug
|   └── post.pug
└── index.pug
```

The main idea is that I want to write a watch task for this, that will get all the filenames in **_modules** subdirectories and write them into **includes.pug** file so it would look something like this:

```
include _footer/footer
include _header/header
```

I've found some gulp packages that could get the filenames and store them in some variables (array), but I don't know, how to transform them to a string and to inject them into another file (well, I can do foreach of array with filenames and then get a string like 'include '+ filename, but the main problem is that I can't find a package that could insert that strings in a file while I'm doing foreach). Any suggestions how can I do this?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-header or https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-insert will prepend strings into files.  If you need help with the other parts I'd like to see your code thus far,  I suggest you also look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-fs

Comment: @Mark Not sure about the first one, but the others may do the thing. I'll check them out, thank you!